# WebDriver - locate dynamic column

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using webdriver to test our application that contain table where the user can change the order of columns in a table,and also can remove/add columns (This is beside new column added by developers).

What is the right way to find the column I need? 
One way is to go over the table header to find the column I am looking for so I have the column index and than I can access the right cell.

Is there other way ? 
What about put unique id/class name for every element in table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things for this situation:

1. Get handle to `table` element, and then navigate accordingly to get the columns or rows. Once you have this, then you can do all operations on them like `click()` etc.
2. Other way is, see the pattern of their `ids`/`css` because, most of the table that I have deal with will be having `ids` like this:

   `grid_name_1
   grid_name_2
   grid_name_3`

Then you can have do this way:

```
String baseLocator = "grid_name_" + clickedRowIndex;
driver.findElement(By.id(baseLocator)).click(); //for click operation
```

Lets say user wants to click on the 3rd row, then `clickedRowIndex` will be `3` which selects the 3rd table row.